# Joomla! 3/2.5: field "file" upload handler - failed to move file... but moved

Tags: file-upload, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.3

I'm working on a content plugin that adds some extra fields to com_content component and one of fields is of type "file" with the following declaration:

```
  <field
      name="zp_zipupl"
      type="file"
      onchange="jQuery(this).closest('form').attr('enctype','multipart/form-data')"
      label="PLG_CONTENT_CUSTOMFIELDZ_ZP_ZIPUPL"
   />
```

...and I'm handling the upload process on onContentPrepare content event like this:

```
function onContentPrepare($context,&$article,&$params,$page){
    $input = new JInputFiles();
    $files = $input->get('jform');

    if($files) foreach ($files as $inputFile) {
        foreach ($inputFile as $file) {
            $tmp_dir = $file['tmp_name'];
            $dest_dir = JPATH_SITE.'/uploads/projects/';
            $file_name_ext = $file['name'];

            JFile::upload($tmp_dir,$dest_dir . $file_name_ext);
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
After I save the article I get the error "Warning: Failed to move file", but if I enter the "uploads/project/" directory the file is there, so it worked, but the field value is not stored in the database.

If I remove "onchange" event for this field, the value is stored in the database, but because the form enctype is not specified, the file isn't uploaded (even if I manully edit the com_content article/tmpl/edit view and set the enctype I have the same problem while uploading).

I have adapted the plugin code for J! 2.5 + same onContentPrepare code => same behaviour, but the file isn't uploaded.

- All directories have the right permissions and exists.
- Joomla! 3.3 / Joomla! 2.5.24 PHP 5.4 (local) / 5.3 (shared hosting)
- $tmp_dir directory - on localhost (Linux, XAMPP) - is
  "opt/lampp/temp/"
- $tmp_dir directory - on shared hosting - is
  "/tmp/"

*Also, less important, onContentPrepareForm if I want to get the value of some field with $form->getValue('field_name'); it doesn't work...

What could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your solution as a proper answer and mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Solution]**
Mainly, I had to use the *onContentBeforeSave* event to get rid of that warning and the value in the database has to be inserted manually. It works on both J! 3.3 and 2.5.x.
TO-DO: preserve the stored database values for fields of type 'file' when saving article without uploading new file.

The code:

```
function onContentBeforeSave($context,$article,$isNew){
    //get jform
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $jform = $jinput->get('jform', null, null);

    //get $_FILES
    $input = new JInputFiles();
    $files = $input->get('jform');
    $uploadDir = $this->params->get('cfz_upload_path');

    if( ! empty($files)) foreach ($files as $file) {
        foreach ($file as $fieldName => $fileVals) {
            $tmp_dir = $fileVals['tmp_name'];
            $dest_dir = JPATH_SITE . $uploadDir;
            $file_name_ext = $fileVals['name'];

            if(JFile::upload($tmp_dir,$dest_dir . $file_name_ext)){
                //append input value to jform
                $jform['attribs'][$fieldName] = $uploadDir . $file_name_ext;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //preserve file field value...
    }

    //add all attribs to $article
    $article->attribs = json_encode($jform['attribs']);
}
```